# How to create a bigger bitmap from an existing bitmap

Tags: android, image, bitmap

I have one Bitmap image. How do I create a bigger bitmap programmatically? I tried creating scaleBitMap, but it is not displaying bigger.

```
int newHeight=900;
Bitmap bg1=Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bg, width, newHeight, false);
canvas.drawBitmap(bg1, null, new Rect(0, 0, getWidth(), newHeight), null);
```

How do I fix this problem?

Comment: this is the not working when use scrollTo  views that wish to internally scroll their content http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#scrollTo%28int,%20int%29

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you should try this instead:

```
int newHeight=900;
int newWidth= bg.getWidth;
Bitmap bg1=Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bg, newWidth, newHeight, true);
```

always worth a try

Answer (score 1):

```
private Bitmap resizeBitmap(Bitmap bitmap, float scaleHeight, float scaleWidth)
{
    int width = bitmap.getWidth();
    int height = bitmap.getHeight();

    int newWidth = (int)(width * scaleWidth);
    int newHeight = (int)(height * scaleHeight);

    return Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, newWidth, newHeight, true);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The Bitmap.createScaledBitmap() is doing what you want, the problem is when you're trying to draw it to the canvas. What is getWidth() returning? Post the rest of the code to give us some context and we can find your problem.

Comment: getWidth() gives the height of screen.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code...

```
public Bitmap getResizeBitmap(Bitmap bitmap, int newHeight, int newWidth)
        {

            int width = bitmap.getWidth();
            int height = bitmap.getHeight();

            float scaleWidth = ((float)newWidth)/width;
            float scaleHeight = ((float)newHeight)/height;

            Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
            matrix.postScale(scaleWidth, scaleHeight);
            Bitmap resizeBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bm, 0, 0, width, height, matrix, true);

            return resizeBitmap;

        }
```

then in onCreate method use this...

```
myImage = Bitmap.createBitmap(BitmapFactory
                    .decodeResource(this.getResources(), R.drawable.mypic));

            myImage.setDensity(1);

            imageview = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageViewId);
            imageview.setImageBitmap(getResizeBitmap(myImage,195, 480));//as per as your requirement
```